# java REST service - can't call from browser

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have been looking at this problem for ages and just can't seem to get it working. Its a simple test java app to provide a REST service.

I have the following web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

<display-name>test2</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>com.crunchify.restjersey</param-value>
</init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test2/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and the following class setup:-

```
package com.crunchify.restjersey;

/**
* @author Crunchify.com
*/

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/ctofservice")
public class CtoFService {
@GET
@Produces("application/xml")
public String convertCtoF() {

    Double fahrenheit;
    Double celsius = 36.8;
    fahrenheit = ((celsius * 9) / 5) + 32;

    String result = "@Produces(\"application/xml\") Output: \n\nC to F Converter Output: \n\n" + fahrenheit;
    return "<ctofservice>" + "<celsius>" + celsius + "</celsius>" + "<ctofoutput>" + result + "</ctofoutput>" + "</ctofservice>";
}

@Path("{c}")
@GET
@Produces("application/xml")
public String convertCtoFfromInput(@PathParam("c") Double c) {
    Double fahrenheit;
    Double celsius = c;
    fahrenheit = ((celsius * 9) / 5) + 32;

    String result = "@Produces(\"application/xml\") Output: \n\nC to F Converter Output: \n\n" + fahrenheit;
    return "<ctofservice>" + "<celsius>" + celsius + "</celsius>" + "<ctofoutput>" + result + "</ctofoutput>" + "</ctofservice>";
}
}
```

pom.xml is as follows:-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>test2</groupId>
<artifactId>test2</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
 <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
      <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20151123</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

and it deploys OK to tomcat:-

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.33
Apr 29, 2016 6:43:08 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs.     Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were    scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during   scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Apr 29, 2016 6:43:08 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig  init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
com.crunchify.restjersey
Apr 29, 2016 6:43:08 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig   logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
class com.crunchify.restjersey.CtoFService
class com.crunchify.restjersey.FtoCService
Apr 29, 2016 6:43:08 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig     init
INFO: No provider classes found.
Apr 29, 2016 6:43:08 PM    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19.1 03/11/2016    02:42 PM'
Apr 29, 2016 6:43:09 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Apr 29, 2016 6:43:09 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Apr 29, 2016 6:43:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2719 ms
```

but when calling in browser as follows:-

```
http://localhost:8080/test2/ctofservice
```

I just get a 
    HTTP Status 404 - /test2/ctofservice

Have checked a lot of other questions and answers but I don't seemto have any of those problems - Any ideas welcomed!!

Comment: What is the name of the war file you are deploying?  test2.war or test2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war ?  If I recall correctly, the default context for a war is the full name (everything before the .war, not just the name of the maven project).  Try http://localhost:8080/test2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ctofservice

Comment: @ManoDestra Having the Path annotation on the class just means that all methods in the class will use that as a base (and then made more specific by additional Path annotations on the methods).  How it is done here is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: can you try http://localhost:8080/test2/test2/ctofservice

Comment: Yes! That works. I thought test2 had to be in there as that is the context root of the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change your web.xml file to this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

<display-name>test2</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>com.crunchify.restjersey</param-value>
</init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And this will be the output:

[image: output]

I hope I have helped you!

Comment: Yes that has resolved the issue. the /test2/ was obviously not needed.